# Chrome extension getting rejected although suggested changes are required

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, permissions, chrome-web-store

I have a chrome extension which is getting rejected because according to them I do not need the tabs permission I am asking for. However, I have looked over my code and my chrome extension would not work without it. I have even tried my chrome extension without the permission and it failed. I am using tabs when doing things such as `chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabid, removeInfo)`, `chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}`, function(tabs), and more which all require tabs permissions. Can someone help me understand why it might be getting rejected? Or if there is a work around.

The funny part is, that my original extension using tabs permission was accepted, but when I sent a revised version in, they rejected that although the changes had nothing to do with tabs.

The specific reasoning I got:

```
Violation reference ID: Purple Potassium
Violation: The following permission(s) need not be requested for the methods/properties implemented by the item:
tabs
How to rectify: Remove the above permission(s). The properties used by the items will continue to function even without requesting these permissions.
```

When I am running my chrome extension without tabs permission, my background.js which holds some of the chrome.tabs code throws this error. It gets resolved if I add the permission back.

```
Error handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of tabs.sendMessage(integer tabId, any message, optional object options, optional function responseCallback): No matching signature.
    at <URL>
```

The code block which throws that error is below.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {method: "getNumber"}, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                currentNumber = response.current;
            });
        });
```

EDIT:

Background.js

```
var tabId = "";
var running = 0;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.text == "what is my tab_id?") {
        tabId = sender.tab.id;
        sendResponse({tab: sender.tab.id});
    }
});

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabid, removeInfo) {
    if(tabid == tabId) {
        console.log("closed tab");
        stop();
    }
});

function stop() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({"monitor": 0}, function() {
    });
    running = 1;
}

function start() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({"monitor": 1}, function() {
    });
    running = 0;
}

function sendSMS(phone_number) {
    var currentNumber = 100000000;
    var timeToPurchase = 0;
    var prevNumber = currentNumber;
    var increase = 0;
    var dropStat = 0;
    var inst = setInterval(function() {
        chrome.storage.sync.get('increment', function(data) {
            increase = data.increment;
        });

        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {method: "getNumber"}, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                currentNumber = response.current;
                lastUpdated = response.lastUp;
                timeToPurchase = response.done;
                dropStat = response.dropStatus;
            });
        });
        if(running == 1) {
            clearInterval(inst);
            return;
        }
        //more logic below to make some api calls

    }, 5000);
}
```

Contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.method == "getNumber") {
            sendResponse({current: 0, lastUp : "time value here", done : 0, dropStatus : 0})
            return true;
        }
        return true;
});

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ text: "what is my tab_id?" }, tabId => {
    console.log('My tabId is', tabId);
 });
```

The function sendSMS is called when a button is pressed on the popup.html

Comment: The `tabs` permission is not needed for those events/methods. As the documentation says it's only needed to read url, pendingUrl, title, or favIconUrl. The error is caused by something else, which you probably are doing wrong, so please show more code. Also note that you don't need chrome.tabs.query() if you already have tabId, but judging by the error your tabId may be `null` so please show how it's defined too.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have updated my code above to include my background.js, contentscript.js. The main time the tabId is used is to check if the page has closed, so I can stop the loop in the function.

Comment: The posted code doesn't need `tabs` permission. There's also no need for chrome.tabs.query.

Comment: @wOxxOm How do I check if the current tab is closed tho? I want my chrome extension to keep running as long as the tab is open even if I am on a different window or tab.

Comment: You already have onRemoved event listener.